# Django: filtering on an annotated datetime?

Tags: django, group-by, django-orm

I have a series of events (with timestamps) that are linked to users:

```
# models.py

from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, db_index=True)
    time = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='events', null=True)
```

I want to find the id of the first such event for each user (to be used in a later subquery). Should be simple, right?

```
activation_event_ids = User.objects  \
    .annotate(first_event_time=Min('events__time'))  \
    .filter(events__time='first_event_time')  \
    .values_list('events__id', flat=True)
```

But this blows up:

```
ValidationError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/gabriel/.virtualenvs/gordon/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.pyc in <module>()
      1 activation_event_ids = User.objects  \
      2     .annotate(first_event_time=Min('km_events__time'))  \
----> 3     .filter(km_events__time='first_event_time')  \
      4     .values_list(km_events__id, flat=True)

/home/gabriel/.virtualenvs/gordon/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.pyc in filter(self, *args, **kwargs)
    619         set.
    620         """
--> 621         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
    622 
    623     def exclude(self, *args, **kwargs):

/home/gabriel/.virtualenvs/gordon/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.pyc in _filter_or_exclude(self, negate, *args, **kwargs)
    637             clone.query.add_q(~Q(*args, **kwargs))
    638         else:
--> 639             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
    640         return clone
    641 

/home/gabriel/.virtualenvs/gordon/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.pyc in add_q(self, q_object, used_aliases, force_having)
   1251                 else:
   1252                     self.add_filter(child, connector, q_object.negated,
-> 1253                             can_reuse=used_aliases, force_having=force_having)
   1254                 if force_having:
   1255                     self.having.end_subtree()

/home/gabriel/.virtualenvs/gordon/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.pyc in add_filter(self, filter_expr, connector, negate, trim, can_reuse, process_extras, force_having)
   1186         else:
   1187             self.where.add((Constraint(alias, col, field), lookup_type, value),
-> 1188                 connector)
   1189 
   1190         if negate:

/home/gabriel/.virtualenvs/gordon/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/where.pyc in add(self, data, connector)
     67 
     68         if hasattr(obj, "prepare"):
---> 69             value = obj.prepare(lookup_type, value)
     70             super(WhereNode, self).add((obj, lookup_type, annotation, value),
     71                 connector)

/home/gabriel/.virtualenvs/gordon/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/where.pyc in prepare(self, lookup_type, value)
    316     def prepare(self, lookup_type, value):
    317         if self.field:
--> 318             return self.field.get_prep_lookup(lookup_type, value)
    319         return value
    320 

/home/gabriel/.virtualenvs/gordon/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.pyc in get_prep_lookup(self, lookup_type, value)
    707         if lookup_type in ('month', 'day', 'week_day'):
    708             return int(value)
--> 709         return super(DateField, self).get_prep_lookup(lookup_type, value)
    710 
    711     def get_prep_value(self, value):

/home/gabriel/.virtualenvs/gordon/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.pyc in get_prep_lookup(self, lookup_type, value)
    308             return value
    309         elif lookup_type in ('exact', 'gt', 'gte', 'lt', 'lte'):
--> 310             return self.get_prep_value(value)
    311         elif lookup_type in ('range', 'in'):
    312             return [self.get_prep_value(v) for v in value]

/home/gabriel/.virtualenvs/gordon/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.pyc in get_prep_value(self, value)
    799 
    800     def get_prep_value(self, value):
--> 801         value = self.to_python(value)
    802         if value is not None and settings.USE_TZ and timezone.is_naive(value):
    803             # For backwards compatibility, interpret naive datetimes in local


/home/gabriel/.virtualenvs/gordon/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.pyc in to_python(self, value)
    783 
    784         msg = self.error_messages['invalid'] % value
--> 785         raise exceptions.ValidationError(msg)
    786 
    787     def pre_save(self, model_instance, add):

ValidationError: [u"'first_event_time' value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]
```

I'm currently using a local SQLite DB. Is it really not possible to filter on annotated datetimes? Or am I just doing something stupid?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to reference the annotation field, you need to use `F`:

```
from django.db.models import F

...

.filter(events__time=F('first_event_time'))
```

For reference, see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#query-expressions

Comment: Wow. So, yes, I was just doing something stupid. But with the F(), this query seems to take an extraordinarily long time (it's been running for about an hour), while without that filter (ie with just the annotation) it returns quite quickly. I'd have thought the annotation would take far longer than the filtering. Any idea what's up? (Or how to see the SQL without actually running the query? The usual method of [inspecting queries after the fact](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running) doesn't work since I have to kill the process)

Comment: Use something like django-devserver or django-debug-toolbar. The former replaces runserver and, amongst other things, shows every query being ran in the shell. The latter displays as an overlay on your site, and also details all the queries that were ran and a number of other useful information. You can technically use both if you want.

Comment: my understanding is that both of those only show queries *after* they have been executed (this is certainly the case for DDT, given that it displays queries from the previous request on the already-rendered page), which doesn't help if the query never finishes. I'll take a closer look at devserver, but I imagine there must be some other way, buried in the Django internals, to find out what query *would be* executed, without actually running it.

Comment: You can try: `str(MyModel.objects.all().query)` where `MyModel.objects.all()` is whatever `QuerySet` you're working with.